# Having a bit of trouble reading in a file that contains specific information in each line

Tags: java, oop

So I am having trouble reading in a file. The file contains 2 integers in the first line, and the rest of the file contains Strings in seperate lines. For some reason my logic in this code, it does not seem to consume each line in the file correctly. I tried to troubleshoot this by printing out what was happening, and it seems like the second nextLine() is not even executing.

```
  while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        try
        {
            String start = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(start); // tried to troubleshoot here
            String [] rowsAndCols = start.split(" "); // part where it should read the first two integers
            System.out.println(rowsAndCols[0]); // tried to troubleshoot here
            int rows = Integer.parseInt(rowsAndCols[0]);
            int cols = Integer.parseInt(rowsAndCols[1]);
            cell = new MazeCell.CellType[rows+2][cols+2];  

            String mazeStart = inputFile.nextLine(); // part where it should begin to read the rest of the file containing strings 
            String [] mazeRowsAndCols = mazeStart.split(" ");
            MazeCell.CellType cell2Add;
```

Comment: `while(inputFile.hasNextLine()) ....`

Comment: Welcome!   You're going to want to give us a little more to go on.   Please show us more of the code, and what you're expecting to happen, and what is happening.   We can't see how inputFile is created or opened, and your while/try blocks aren't complete (feel free to remove irrelevant bits, but make the structure complete).

Comment: Still having issues where each line is read in through String start = inputFile.nextLine();

Comment: We need more to go on, but one thing to look at, if the first line of the file is the only one that contains the rows and cols, you'll want to read and parse that line outside of the loop.  Right now, it's trying to read two lines each cycle through the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your description above, only the first line contains Integers, so your while loop is wrong as it is trying to convert every line into Integers.

Split into the code into

```
if (inputFile.hasNextLine()) 
{
    String start = inputFile.nextLine();
    String [] rowsAndCols = start.split(" "); // part where it should read the first two integers
    int rows = Integer.parseInt(rowsAndCols[0]);
    int cols = Integer.parseInt(rowsAndCols[1]);
}
```

then a while loop for the String reading